# Any books of running large (100+) development teams?

Tags: team-management, software-development, motivation, books

Running a large (100+) development team is quite different to 10 or even 40 people, manual control stops working. What are the books on how to do it the most effectively?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking software, tools or resource recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. In your case I would recommend reading "The Mythical Man Month" as a primer.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. So when you think The Mythical Man Month would be obsolete?

Comment: You'd have to define the criteria by which a factual book becomes obsolete before I could answer that. It might not be relevant to your needs, but I don't know what those needs are! However given what I *do* know from the brief question I would say it would be an interesting primer rather than a solution resource.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic per our Help Center as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Spotify is running a 250+ man team and has some videos and a 13 pages paper, find links at: http://blog.crisp.se/2012/11/14/henrikkniberg/scaling-agile-at-spotify

There are a number of Scaling Agile frameworks which have books:

- LeSS: Large-Scale Scrum, http://less.works/ (My favorite, documented broadly both online and in this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Large-Scale-Scrum-More-Craig-Larman/dp/0321985710](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321985710))
- SAFe: Scaled Agile Framework, http://www.scaledagileframework.com/books/
- Nexus: https://www.scrum.org/Resources/The-Nexus-Guide

Also checkout the Agile Scaling Knowledge Matrix, which also contains other frameworks for scaling software development: http://www.agilescaling.org/ask-matrix.html